# rails on windows: No Rakefile found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

despite advice to the contrary, I am attempting to run rails on windows.

When I try the rake command

`C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1>rake`

I get

```
rake aborted! 
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, 
Rakefile.rb)
```

I am simply following a tutorial I found on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Rake from within the same folder as a Rakefile, as the error indicates